# What is the correct way to use lifetimes with a struct in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to write this structure:

```
struct A {
    b: B,
    c: C,
}

struct B {
    c: &C,
}

struct C;
```

The `B.c` should be borrowed from `A.c`.

```
A ->
  b: B ->
    c: &C -- borrow from --+
                           |
  c: C  <------------------+
```

This is what I tried:

```
struct C;

struct B<'b> {
    c: &'b C,
}

struct A<'a> {
    b: B<'a>,
    c: C,
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    fn new<'b>() -> A<'b> {
        let c = C;
        A {
            c: c,
            b: B { c: &c },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

But it fails:

```
error[E0597]: `c` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:24
   |
17 |             b: B { c: &c },
   |                        ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
18 |         }
19 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'b as defined on the method body at 13:5...
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     fn new<'b>() -> A<'b> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `c`
  --> src/main.rs:17:24
   |
16 |             c: c,
   |                - value moved here
17 |             b: B { c: &c },
   |                        ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `c` has type `C`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I've read the Rust documentation on ownership, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Sibling references (ie, referencing part of the same struct) is not possible in Rust.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There is actually more than one reason why the code above fails. Let's break it down a little and explore a few options on how to fix it.

First let's remove the `new` and try building an instance of `A` directly in `main`, so that you see that the first part of the problem has nothing to do with lifetimes:

```
struct C;

struct B<'b> {
    c: &'b C,
}

struct A<'a> {
    b: B<'a>,
    c: C,
}

fn main() {
    // I copied your new directly here
    // and renamed c1 so we know what "c"
    // the errors refer to
    let c1 = C;

    let _ = A {
        c: c1,
        b: B { c: &c1 },
    };
}
```

this fails with:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `c1`
  --> src/main.rs:20:20
   |
19 |         c: c1,
   |            -- value moved here
20 |         b: B { c: &c1 },
   |                    ^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `c1` has type `C`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

what it says is that if you assign `c1` to `c`, you move its ownership to `c` (i.e. you can't access it any longer through `c1`, only through `c`). This means that all the references to `c1` would be no longer valid. But you have a `&c1` still in scope (in B), so the compiler can't let you compile this code.

The compiler hints at a possible solution in the error message when it says that type `C` is non-copyable. If you could make a copy of a `C`, your code would then be valid, because assigning `c1` to `c` would create a new copy of the value instead of moving ownership of the original copy.

We can make `C` copyable by changing its definition like this:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct C;
```

Now the code above works. Note that what [@matthieu-m comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589054/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-lifetimes-with-a-struct-in-rust#comment43603185_27589054) is still true: [we can't store both the reference to a value and the value itself in B](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) (we're storing a reference to a value and a COPY of the value here). That's not just for structs, though, it's how ownership works.

Now, if you don't want to (or can't) make `C` copyable, you can store references in both `A` and `B` instead.

```
struct C;

struct B<'b> {
    c: &'b C,
}

struct A<'a> {
    b: B<'a>,
    c: &'a C, // now this is a reference too
}

fn main() {
    let c1 = C;
    let _ = A {
        c: &c1,
        b: B { c: &c1 },
    };
}
```

All good then? Not really... we still want to move the creation of `A` back into a `new` method. And THAT's where we will run in trouble with lifetimes. Let's move the creation of `A` back into a method:

```
impl<'a> A<'a> {
    fn new() -> A<'a> {
        let c1 = C;
        A {
            c: &c1,
            b: B { c: &c1 },
        }
    }
}
```

as anticipated, here's our lifetime error:

```
error[E0597]: `c1` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:17
   |
17 |             c: &c1,
   |                 ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
20 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 13:1...
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | impl<'a> A<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0597]: `c1` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:24
   |
18 |             b: B { c: &c1 },
   |                        ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
19 |         }
20 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 13:1...
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | impl<'a> A<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

this is because `c1` is destroyed at the end of the `new` method, so we can't return a reference to it.

```
fn new() -> A<'a> {
    let c1 = C; // we create c1 here
    A {
        c: &c1,          // ...take a reference to it
        b: B { c: &c1 }, // ...and another
    }
} // and destroy c1 here (so we can't return A with a reference to c1)
```

One possible solution is to create `C` outside of `new` and pass it in as a parameter:

```
struct C;

struct B<'b> {
    c: &'b C,
}

struct A<'a> {
    b: B<'a>,
    c: &'a C
}

fn main() {
    let c1 = C;
    let _ = A::new(&c1);
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    fn new(c: &'a C) -> A<'a> {
        A {c: c, b: B{c: c}}
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a34324a91735eca6b10478135df673b5&version=stable&mode=debug)

Comment: Do you (or anyone else) know if there's a way to make the compiler happy while still creating "C" inside of the new fn?

Comment: @Sushisource technically you could return references with a static lifetime (`&'static C`), but that's rarely useful in practice

Comment: Does anyone know if now it would somehow be possible to do something about this using `Pin`s? The example in the docs shows how to achieve something similar by replacing `&'a T` with `*const T`. However, I don't see any way to somehow replace `B<'a>` with a raw pointer. Is there any?

Comment: In a similar situation I ended up using `Arc<>` for this case, which is a bit overkill IMO, but I did not see a more crustacean way of doing yet.

Comment: Allocate the struct C on heap instead of stack and use RC.

Answer (score 8):

After checking with Manishearth and eddyb on the #rust IRC, I believe it's not possible for a struct to store a reference to itself or a portion of itself.  So what you are trying to do isn't possible within Rust's type system.

Comment: Hi Rufflewind, do you know what the alternative is if storing a reference to a portion of struct itself is not possible?

Comment: @nybon The most typical solution would be one of either referring to the value directly (i.e. `self.b.c` in the above example, with `self.c` omitted entirely), or if that is undesirable, providing a method that generates references to C on demand (and those references can correctly be annotated with the struct's lifetime).

Comment: This is a problem. I'm using libgit2 (git2) and everything points to the repository. So if I want to create my own wrapper that stores some things like heads, branches, the last commit for the graph... everything needs to be tied to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party (replying from the future) and totally new to Rust, but I am getting there (sort of). Building on the answer this worked for me, at least compile wise.

```
impl<'a> A<'a> {
fn new() -> A<'a> {
    let c1:&'a C = &C;
    A {
        c: c1,
        b: B { c: c1 },
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This... is not going to work 95% of the cases. It only works because [`C` is special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ouroboros](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/latest/ouroboros/) crate:

```rust
use ouroboros::self_referencing;

struct C;

struct B<'b> {
    c: &'b C,
}

#[self_referencing]
struct A {
    c: C,

    #[borrows(c)]
    #[covariant]
    b: B<'this>,
}

fn main() {
    let c = C;

    let a = A::new(c, |c| B { c: &c });
}
```